# CFML on BlueDragon datasource could not be found or was invalid

Tags: coldfusion, datasource, bluedragon

This is the error I get when trying to open any of my CFML pages that work with the database:

```
Type Database Detail The datasource thenightclub could not be found or was
invalid Extended Info javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name thenightclub 
is not bound in this Context.
```

Comment: I've not used BlueDragon, but have you set up the datasource correctly? I guess theres a BlueDragon administrator where you can set it up? In ColdFusion and Railo you can then verify the datasource.

Comment: Yes I did in fact set the DSN correctly.  My configuration is BlueDragon running on Windows Server 2012 with ColdFusion.  The database backend is SQL Server.

Comment: 'ColdFusion on BlueDragon'? There is no such thing. They are different products that do the same thing. This is akin to saying 'Apache on IIS'

Comment: I am sure you may have deemed DSN to something else. It is DataSource Name which you need to specify in your BlueDragon admin. Log in to BD admin, create a datasource with the same name your application is expecting it (so that you do not have to make any change in code files.)

Comment: I am quite sure he meant CFML on BlueDragon as the two terms are used interchangeably, just as "coke" frequently does not refer to a Coke. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Giving credit to CFML_Developer for the comment:

"I am sure you may have deemed DSN to something else. It is DataSource Name which you need to specify in your BlueDragon admin. Log in to BD admin, create a datasource with the same name your application is expecting it (so that you do not have to make any change in code files.)" – @CFML_Developer